# Install Ansible Windows Machine

Tags: python, ansible

I have tried installing ansible through **pip install ansible** but whenever i get the following error trying to use it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\ruan.greyling\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\ansible.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ruan.greyling\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ansible\cli\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    check_blocking_io()
  File "C:\Users\ruan.greyling\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ansible\cli\__init__.py", line 34, in check_blocking_io
    if not os.get_blocking(fd):
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'get_blocking'
```

I have python and pip installed on the machine.

Comment: [_You cannot use a Windows system for the Ansible control node._](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/installation_distros.html#installing-ansible-on-windows) https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/os_guide/windows_faq.html#windows-faq-ansible

Comment: Thanks for the response. I got it working by launching an aws instance as a control node.

Answer (score 15):

This is why you are getting this error.

- Windows without WSL is not natively supported as a control node ([more in the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#control-node-requirements))
- If you want to run the Control node on Windows use WSL

Good practice code repository and sync to your Linux Control node from Windows machine.

Comment: Additional link from documentation to a blog post on [Why no Ansible controller for Windows?](http://blog.rolpdog.com/2020/03/why-no-ansible-controller-for-windows.html)

Answer (score -3):

It looks like this may be a version compatibility issue with Python 3.11. I recommend upgrading to the latest version of Python and then running the command again.

Comment: `os.get_blocking` is listed as [only available on Unix](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/os.html#os.get_blocking), so upgrading Python will not solve this issue. As others have said, the issue is that Windows without WSL is [not supported as a control node](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#control-node-requirements).